# How to build ctags 5.8 in Windows

Tags: c, ctags

I have tried to re-build the Ctags 5.8 source code(http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/) for win32 by using Borland C++ 5.5 compiler follow the instruction http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2288 , however I get the compile error that I have no idea about it.

```
 gnu_regex/regex.c:
 Error E2139 gnu_regex/regex_internal.h 362: Declaration missing ;
 Error E2303 gnu_regex/regex_internal.c 23: Type name expected
 Error E2303 gnu_regex/regex_internal.c 41: Type name expected
 Error E2147 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 104: 'RE_TRANSLATE_TYPE' cannot start a parameter declaration
 Error E2303 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 110: Type name expected
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 225: Undefined symbol 'no_sub' in function       re_compile_pattern
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 225: Undefined symbol 'RE_NO_SUB' in function re_compile_pattern
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 228: Undefined symbol 'newline_anchor' in function re_compile_pattern
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 272: Undefined symbol 'buffer' in function re_compile_fastmap
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 273: Undefined symbol 'fastmap' in function re_compile_fastmap
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 283: Undefined symbol 'fastmap_accurate' in function re_compile_fastmap
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 306: Undefined symbol 'buffer' in function re_compile_fastmap_iter
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 308: Undefined symbol 'syntax' in function re_compile_fastmap_iter
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 308: Undefined symbol 'RE_ICASE' in function re_compile_fastmap_iter
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 425: Undefined symbol 'can_be_null' in function re_compile_fastmap_iter
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 475: Undefined symbol 'RE_SYNTAX_POSIX_EXTENDED' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 475: Undefined symbol 'RE_SYNTAX_POSIX_BASIC' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 477: Undefined symbol 'buffer' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 478: Undefined symbol 'allocated' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 479: Undefined symbol 'used' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 482: Undefined symbol 'fastmap' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 483: Undefined symbol 'fastmap' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 486: Undefined symbol 'RE_ICASE' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 491: Undefined symbol 'RE_DOT_NEWLINE' in function regcomp
 Error E2451 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 492: Undefined symbol 'RE_HAT_LISTS_NOT_NEWLINE' in function regcomp
 Error E2228 gnu_regex/regcomp.c 492: Too many error or warning messages in function regcomp
```

Can anyone advise me what I was missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it using gcc?

Comment: Well, from the error messages, I think that could be missing some references. I think I am missing something but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the REGEX_DEFINE of mk_bc5.mk as below:

```
REGEX_DEFINE = -DHAVE_REGCOMP -DREGEX_MALLOC -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -D__USE_GNU -Dbool=int -Dfalse=0 -Dtrue=1 -Dstrcasecmp=stricmp
```